# How to query a specific document by id

Tags: solr

From a previous query I already have the document ID (the *uniqueKey* in this schema is 'track_id') of the document I'm interested in.
Then I would like to query a sequence of words on that document while highlighting the match.

I can't seem to be able to combine the search parameters in a successful way (all my google searches return purple links :\ ), although I've already tried many combinations these past few days. I also know the field where the matches will be if that's any use in terms of improving match speed.

I'm guessing it should be something like this:

```
/select?q=track_id:{key_i_already_have} AND/&/{part_I_dont_know} word1 word2 word3
```

Currently, since I can't combine these two search parameters, I'm only querying the words and thus getting several results from several documents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would q=track_id:ID AND (field:word1 OR field:word2 OR field:word3) work?

Comment: You can also put the track_id:ID into the fq part. That way you don't need AND and ID is not contributing to the score/ranking calculations (a tiny bit faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try applying Filter Query for id. So it will filter your search query to that id, and then search in that document for all the keywords, and highlight them.

Your query will look like:

```
/select?fq=track_id:DOC_ID&q=word1 word2 word3
```

Just make sure your "id" field in schema.xml is defined of the type string to apply filter queries on it.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Comment: This method also worked but since @MatsLindh answered first I'll leave this mention here.

Answer (score 10):

From Solr 4 you can use the [realtime get](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RealTime+Get), which is much more faster than searching the index by id.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/get?ids=id1,id2,id3
```

> For index updates to be visible (searchable), some kind of commit must reopen a searcher to a new point-in-time view of the index. The realtime get feature allows retrieval (by unique-key) of the latest version of any documents without the associated cost of reopening a searcher. This is primarily useful when using Solr as a NoSQL data store and not just a search index.